Problem with Django class-based LogoutView

Here is my user urls.py code
from django.urls import path
from users_app import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='logout'),
]


You can not visit the LogoutView: only send a POST request to it to logout.

The LogoutView does not render a HTML page, it only accepts POST requests: such POST request will log out the user and redirect to the path/view specified by the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL setting [Django-doc].
You can define a template yourself:
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path(
        'login/',
        auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'),
        name='login',
    ),
    path('do-logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='do-logout'),
    path(
        'logout/',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'),
        name='logout',
    ),
]
and then in the template thus make a POST request with a mini-form:
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'do-logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %} <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>

Hey, I'm using this question as a canonical for this particular problem. Your answer here adds some new content that isn't present in your answer there, might make sense to edit your answer there?

@AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, you are right. I will try to update the linked answer this afternoon :)

This is the another way to logout without using LogoutView by using logout_view function.
views.py file
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('index')

urls.py file
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import logout

urlpatterns = [

    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
 
    ]

In Template and in html file
 <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" >
 <span href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</span>
 </a>

From this line of code you can redirect to your index page. In my project i am facing same problem that

This page isn't working

But i am trying function based logout view then it succeed

This actually opens you up to CSRF attacks where anyone can log your users out of your site (Which is what the builtin view is actually trying to avoid).
